# Python DataFrame.fillna() is treating 0 as NA and replacing it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a column that contains distances ranging from 0-100. There are missing values that can be filled by calculating based on another column. I only want to replace the NAs not the 0s. Those should stay as 0.

When I use data['Column1'].fillna(data['Column2'], inplace=True) it also replaces the values in Column1 that equal 0.

Comment: Please produce a minimal, complete, and reproducible example of this bug. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: `fillna` doesn't replace zeros

Comment: @MykolaZotko you are correct. I tried reproducing this issue, and it's not replacing the 0s. I was pretty sure I did it multiple times yesterday and it did replace the 0s.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': [10, 20, np.nan, 0, 50, np.nan],
                     'Column2': [5, np.nan, 30, 0, np.nan, 60]})
```

that is

```
   Column1  Column2
0     10.0      5.0
1     20.0      NaN
2      NaN     30.0
3      0.0      0.0
4     50.0      NaN
5      NaN     60.0
```

using mask

```
mask = data['Column1'].isna()
data.loc[mask, 'Column1'] = data.loc[mask, 'Column2']

print(data)
```

which gives

```
  Column1  Column2
0     10.0      5.0
1     20.0      NaN
2     30.0     30.0
3      0.0      0.0
4     50.0      NaN
5     60.0     60.0
```